# get a particular object from jsonBody with query param of request url in wiremock

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

What should be the mapping object if 
1) I need to pass my query 
2) the query should be used to send one object out of an array of objects

```
 curl -X POST --data '
{ "request": 
           { "url": "/jsons?id=someID", "method": "GET" },
 "response": 
           { "status": 200, "jsonBody": {"objs":[{"id":"1","name":"abc"},{"id":"2","name":"cde" 
                                                 {"id":"someID","name":"efg"}]}}}
'http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/new
```

I want the above url to return just {"id":"someID","name":"efg"}

How should i change the above mapping to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response should have one object for that particular get request with query param and not array of objects.

For your example it should be something like this

```
curl -X POST --data '
{ "request": 
{ "url": "/jsons?id=someID", "method": "GET" },
"response": 
{ "status": 200, "jsonBody": {"objs": {"id":"someID","name":"efg"}}}}
'http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/new
```